# How can I autocomplete a console line I wrote before?

Tags: command-line, command-history

If I have typed in `Service apache` and `service tomcat` for example,
how do I switch to previously written stuff?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Page up/Page down keys.

Comment: You should really consider taking a basics training or buying a beginners book. There are all kind of advice in there for an easy navigation through the console

Comment: You could type ctrl + r at the same time then start typing. It does a history search with your most recent commands first.